# implement firebaseui and conflict appcompat-v7:27.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio

[This is my module.app error on line 23 please help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsZWo.jpg)

Comment: Try using this `implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0'`

Answer (score 1):

In your `build.gradle (:app)` Add this lines at the end.

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            details.useVersion '27.1.1'
     }

   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui